# Intuition for smaller upper critical dimension in quantum statistical physics

Tags: phase-transition, statistical-mechanics

In the theory of phase transitions, the upper critical dimension (UCD) is the dimension of space above which the phase transition is well captured by mean-field theory. For instance, it is well known that the UCD of the classical O(N) model is 4. The intuitive reason is that (for a lattice model), the number of neighbors increases with increasing dimension. Thus one expects that at some high enough dimension, the law of large numbers starts to apply and that we can replace the effective field induced by the neighbor by its average, giving rise to the effectiveness of mean-field theory.

For quantum systems instead, it is known that the UCD of quantum phase transition (QPT) is typically lower. For instance, the UCD for the quantum O(N) model is 3. I of course know the standard argument: by the mapping from a d-dimensional quantum system at zero temperature (in imaginary time) to (d+1)-dimensional classical system, one readily recovers that result.

I am instead looking for an alternative, intuitive, reasoning, that does not involve using the above mapping. What in the quantumness of the spin operators in the case of a quantum Heisenberg model, say, makes it more mean-field-like than the classical Heisenberg model? One could even think very naively that "quantum fluctuations" should instead *increase* the UCD (since there are more fluctuations than in the classical case) than lower it...

Answer (score 1):

The "quantum fluctuation" that people refer to, IMO is ultimately just corresponding to the fact that you can have nontrivial phase transitions in ground states for quantum systems, as long as you have competing noncommuting terms in the Hamiltonian.

Just to be clear, as an example, the classical Ising model $H=-\sum Z_iZ_j$ is just simply ordered at $T=0$, and because it "*lacks thermal fluctuation*", the order parameter is strictly $m=1$, the correlation function doesn't decay at all $C(r)\equiv 1$, and the entire system is really just reduced to a trivial one body problem. The moment you have a noncommuting term $-\epsilon\sum X_i$, "the *quantum fluctuation* introduced by the transverse field" lets the system have nontrivial order parameter value $1>m>0$, and the correlation function decays to that value in an at least a bit more complicated way $C(r)\sim m^2+ae^{-r/\xi}$ etc. These explanations in the "" is an interesting way to understand the situation, but is almost not well-defined.

I'm writing "almost not well-defined", because (as you wrote) you can map this situation to an anisotropic classical Ising model in $d+1$ dimensions with some finite temperature $T>0$, and in that model, nothing is quantum. So, my point is, "quantum fluctuation" is like a magic word that only lets you understand why interesting things can happen at $T=0$ at all (classically, the GS needs to be always completely ordered), so you can't really hope for a good "intuition" coming out of it to answer your question.
I personally don't know any other way to understand the lowering of the UCD for quantum systems than the Suzuki-Trotter mapping (and other quantum-to-classical mapping that are morally the same).

For that matter, there are actually cases where a quantum stat-mech model in $d$-dimension (and $T=0$) goes through a quantum phase transition that has the universality class of a $T>0$ $d$-dimensional classical phase transition. This is called "dimensional reduction" and you can find references in papers, although I haven't seen a text book that mentions it.
(e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/0606042.pdf )
I guess the fact that this kind of example can exist, is really telling us that a unified way of understanding these things must be pretty hard.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though it does not really address the issue (which might not have any good solution). What is funny is that those "quantum fluctuations" actually make the system more mean-field, which is in a sense the opposite of having strong fluctuations: they even stabilize order. This is the opposite to disorder, which can increase the upper critical dimension, even for disordered systems, as it happens in the (classical) random field Ising model (which has an upper critical dimension of 6, and dimension reduction down to dimension 5ish).

Comment: My main point was that by considering $T=0$ (which is the usual case for discussing quantum phase transitions), you are already "totally eliminating thermal fluctuation", but "have quantum fluctuation instead". So, it then becomes a comparison between thermal vs quantum fluctuation, and the latter happens to be "stronger" in many cases, is what the dimensionality observation tells us (although not always, because of the dimensional reduction cases I raise). BTW, could you give me a reference for the RFIM? E.g. in arXiv:1012.0653 they say d_uc=6 for both.

Comment: For RFIM d_uc=6 indeed, but dimensional reduction breaks down around d=5 (the two are not in contradiction). This is a review by two experts of the problem: https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.03530

Comment: Thanks for the reference. One thing I should make sure is that the "dimensional reduction" that's discussed in your ref is that about random fields, and is different from the "dimensional reduction" I was talking about. Mine was purely about the quantum-classical correspondence; since usually d-dim q-system = d+1-dim c-system, when that fails and d-dim q-system = d-dim c-system, people also call that "dimensional reduction". I thought that was more relevant to your original question asking about the quantum fluctuation. I think the "RFIM dim red" is a pretty peculiar thing about random fields.

Comment: Thanks for the precision, the one of RFIM is of a different kind indeed.